# How to apply_filter / add_filter within 2 others (simultaneous?) add_filter

Tags: filters, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm setting up a new form tracking system for my website (the form framework is Gravity forms).

The codebase consists in a parent theme, plus 3 child theme (one for the main website, one for the shop, and another for another branch of the business).

I have a general class in the parent theme which sets up a basic tracking for every gravityforms form using the `gform_after_submission` filter.

```php
class CustomGF {

 // ... some vars

  public function __construct() {
    // Events tracking
    add_filter( 'gform_after_submission', [$this, 'track_conversion'], 10, 2 );
   
    // ...other construct functions
   
   }
   
   public function track_conversion($entry, $form) {
     $trackingArgs = [
       // ... some arguments
     ];

    $trackingArgs = apply_filters('ll/tracking_args', $trackingArgs);
    // ... tracking code here
   }
}
```

After the basic setup, for some specific forms I want to alter the tracking arguments.

So in my child theme I have an additional class which uses the `gform_after_submission_{form_id}' filter to alter the behavior of the tracking for some forms:

```php
class GFChild extends CustomGF {
  
  public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'gform_after_submission_9', [$this, 'submission_business_visit'], 10, 2);
  }

  public function submission_business_visit($entry, $form) {
    add_filter('ll/tracking_args', function() {
       $newArgs = [
         // ... new args here
       ];
       
       return $newArgs;
    }
  }
}
```

But apparently the  `add_filter('ll/tracking_args')` call in the child theme is not working. Any advice on how to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ll/tracking_args` filter is called by the `track_conversion()` method, and this function is added to the execution in the constructor of the `CustomGF` class.

The `GFChild` class has its own constructor, so the constructor of the base class `CustomGF` is not executed. In the `GFChild` constructor also add `track_conversion()` function to `ll/tracking_args` filter or call parent constructor.

```
class GFChild extends CustomGF {

    public function __construct() {
        // Events tracking
        add_filter( 'gform_after_submission', [$this, 'track_conversion'], 10, 2 );

        add_action( 'gform_after_submission_9', [$this, 'submission_business_visit'], 10, 2);
    }
}
```

Or

```
class GFChild extends CustomGF {

    public function __construct() {
        //
        // call parent constructor at the beginning or end
        //
        parent::__construct();

        add_action( 'gform_after_submission_9', [$this, 'submission_business_visit'], 10, 2);
    }
}
```